# While loop on mysql DB

Tags: mysql

First of all, sorry for my noobish question, because I'm pretty sure it is.

I'm using MySQL 5.5.53 on an Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm trying to delete all users with a username starting with the letter "z" from a database. But I also need to delete their rights and remove them from the group they belong too.

The only common point between these tables is the user_id in the user table.

Below, this is the method I'm trying to use to delete a user. Once it works for it, it'll be easy as abc for the other tables.

Unfortunately for this does not work:

I create a file "clearusers.sql":

```
CREATE PROCEDURE clearusers()
BEGIN
        SELECT @count := COUNT(*) FROM db_user WHERE username like 'z%';
        WHILE @count > 0 DO
                SELECT @user_id := user_id FROM db_user WHERE username LIKE 'z%' LIMIT 1;
                delete * from db_user where user_id = @user_id;
                @count = @count -1;
        END WHILE;
END;
```

Then I do this:

> mysql -u root -p mysqldb < clearusers.sql

Then I get this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. So to anybody : Thanks by advance for your help.

Proc.

Comment: Question edited! Sorry for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found myself what's going wrong with my script here are the wrong and fixed version:

What was wrong in comment:

```
--Missing delimiter change
    CREATE PROCEDURE clearusers()
    BEGIN
            SELECT @count := COUNT(*) FROM db_user WHERE username like 'z%';
            WHILE @count > 0 DO
                    SELECT @user_id := user_id FROM db_user WHERE username LIKE 'z%' LIMIT 1;
--Star not needed for the delete
                    delete * from db_user where user_id = @user_id;
--Select missing before @count
                    @count = @count -1;
            END WHILE;
    END;
--missing back to original delimiter.
--missing call procedure.
```

Good:

```
DELIMITER çç
CREATE PROCEDURE clearusers()
BEGIN
        SELECT @count := COUNT(*) FROM db_user WHERE username like 'z%';
        WHILE @count > 0 DO
                SELECT @user_id := user_id FROM db_user WHERE username LIKE 'z%' LIMIT 1;
                DELETE FROM db_user where user_id = @user_id;
                SELECT @count := @count -1;
        END WHILE;
END;
çç

DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: which is basically doing hundreds of queries when one is sufficient. This is not the correct answer even though it's your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a stored procedure for this. What you need is one line of sql

```
DELETE FROM db_user WHERE user_id LIKE 'z%';
```

That is all. What your stored procedure is doing is iterating through all the users in your table with names beginning with z and deleting them one by one. That could mean hundreds, thousands or even millions of repeated queries depending on the size of the data.

Generally as a rule of thumb, when you find yourself looping through a result set and doing another query with those results, there is another way that does not involve loops and repeated queries.